"Ça me fait chier": I don't understand the conjugation behind this expression
Why we say 'ça me fait chier' and not 'ça me fais chier' is it because the subject is il ?

The verb agrees with the subject, ça is the subject, 3rd person singular., me is the object.

Ça (that) is indeed a third person singular, like il or elle. You would use fais at the first or second person singular:

Je me fais chier.
Tu me fais chier.

but

On se/me fait chier.


I see thank you

if you consider, 'Le Français, ça me fait chier'. 'Ça' stands for 'Le Français', and is therefore 3rd person singular.

@MrE Not exactly. Depending on whether you are talking about someone or the language, that would be either  Le Français, il me fait chier or Le français, ça me fait chier.

@jlliagre In my sentence, 'ça' stands for `Le Français', and that implies it is the language, not the person. If it was the person, it would not be 'ça', it would be 'il' as you mentioned. OP is talking about why the verb 'fait' is 3rd person singular when used with 'ça'. You are talking about something completely different.

@MrE You missed my point. Le Français can't be anything but a Frenchman. The language is written le français, lowercase.

Sorry de te faire chier avec ça ;-)

After thinking about it, Le Français, ça me fait chier is also possible if ça refers to not to the Frenchman but to a situation related to him.
